# Mod-rewrite Trailing Slash Issue

Tags: mod-rewrite

There doesn't seem to be much info on this topic so I'm going to outline my specific problem then maybe we can shape the question and the answer into something a bit more universal.

I have this rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bookkeepers/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?franchise=$1
```

Which is changes this URL

```
http://example.com/location/kings-lynn
```

Into this one

```
http://example.com/location/index.php?franchise=kings-lynn
```

The problem I am having is that if I add a trailing slash

```
http://example.com/location/kings-lynn/
```

then the query string is returned as

```
franchise=kings-lynn/
```

and for some reason none of my CSS and Javascript files are being loaded.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've posted an answer about the regular expression matching.  To fix the CSS/Javascript problem, you should look at the server log to see what's being requested.  You may have to add a [R,L] to that RewriteRule, but I've never understood that part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Paul Tomblin said, the .+ is being greedy; that is, it's matching as much as it can.

`^(.+[^/])/?$` tells it to match anything, followed by a character that isn't a /, then followed by an optional /.  This has the effect of not capturing the trailing /.

The most probable reason your CSS and Javascript doesn't work is you're using a relative path, like src="my.js".  When there's a trailing slash, it looks like a directory, so your browser will look for /location/kings-lynn/my.js.  You can fix this simply by using an absolute path to your files (e.g. /location/my.js).

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the (.+) is being greedy matched.  In that case, you could try

```
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/?$ index.php?franchise=$1
```

This makes sure that the first group (in the brackets) doesn't end in a slash.

Comment: Nice. This fixed my trailing slash problem (but not the lack of CSS issue).

Don't suppose you could talk through how this works could you?

Comment: The regular expression matches a group consisting of 1 or more of any characters, followed by any character other than a slash.  Outside the group you're optionally matching a slash.  Before my change, the slash might have ended up in the group.