# Getting 500 error after adding '/' in the URL path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server

I have a web app which is written in PHP and using apache ubuntu server.

Whenever I try to visit any URL with '/' in the end, it shows 500 Internal Error.

Eg: "https://webapp.com/features" - Works fine

"https://webapp.com/features/" - Throws 500 Error

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)$ index.php?profile=$1 [NC]

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

I tried removeing some parts from .htaccess file, but still does not work.

Is it something to do with Apache config?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [trailing slash gives internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779831/trailing-slash-gives-internal-server-error)

Comment: The http status 500 indicates an "internal server error". No details are handed out the client for security reasons. So you, as the operator, need to look inside that server to learn the actual issue. You have access. So go and look what the issue is instead of guessing or asking others who do _not_ have access. Your http server writes log files, one is the error log file. That is where you can _read_ what the actual issue is. _You cannot develop or operate a web page or service without monitoring that file!_

Comment: @fraggley Actually no, the answer you referenced does _not_ answer the question. It shows  a workaround, but it does not answer the question for the "why".

Comment: @fraggley Thankyou for the comment, thought I found the solution but my CSS does not load up correct. So is there any way to remove the trailing slash if user adds it from the URL and not show the 500 Error?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Removed Trailing Slash From The URL With Permanent Redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Add this to your .htaccess file.